# Updating a NVarChar(MAX) column with Linq causing an error

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to make an update on an existing value in my database using Linq in C#.

I instantiate the variable:

```
var projectTrackingEntity = context.project_trackings.Single(pt => pt.project_id == projectId);
```

Then I update the action column(it is a `NVarChar(MAX)`), but I am checking if it already has an action. If so I just add on to it with a semi-colon eg. action1;action2

When I call:

```
context.SubmitChanges();
```

I get this error while debugging:

> System.NotSupportedException: SQL Server does not handle comparison of
>   NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types.

I have tried setting `UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never`, but that doesn't fix the problem.

EDIT: Adding the code where I update the actions (the variable "action" is a string)

```
var actions = projectTrackingEntity.action.Split(';');
bool equalActions = false;
foreach (string a in actions)
{
    if (string.Equals(a, action, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        equalActions = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!equalActions)
{
    projectTrackingEntity.action = string.IsNullOrEmpty(projectTrackingEntity.action) ? //if
        action : //true
        projectTrackingEntity.action + ';' + action; //false
}

context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Are you sure the column in sql server is an nvarchar and not an ntext as the error suggests?

Comment: i added the column myself and it is indeed a nvarchar(MAX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1:**

For fix this issue just `open the dbml file` with `xml editor` and set the `updatecheck to Never` as follows:

```
<column canbenull="true" dbtype="Xml" name="PermissionsXml" type="System.Xml.Linq.XElement" updatecheck="Never"></column>
```

**Method 2:**

Change your field in to a `VARCHAR(max)`

**Method 3:**

change UpdateCheck to `UpdateCheck.WhenChanged`

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: I added the UpdateCheck="Never", still doesn't work.

The column was originally a varchar, I thought the problem was that a varchar couldn't hold a ';' so I changed it to a nvarchar. This didn't change anything.

Comment: @AdamCalvert-Piotrowicz try to do "Method 3"

Comment: @AdamCalvert-Piotrowicz what is your EF version ?

Comment: @AdamCalvert-Piotrowicz check that on "web.config" under attribute "assembly="System.Data.Entity" ? and your sql version ? can you put code for generated model also ?

Comment: the EntityFramework version is 4.3.1.0, the generated model has this heading: [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_action", DbType="NVarChar(MAX)", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]

Comment: @AdamCalvert-Piotrowicz could you put your whole code with related to your updation ? (put your code on your post.Don't put it on comment section )

Comment: UPDATE: you were right with method 2. I already had that field set to NVARCHAR(MAX), I just didn't have ALL the fields in that table updated( some of the older fields used "text" types ).

Answer (score 0):

Almost seems like your DAL classes picked up the property as the wrong type in it's automatic detection? Can you manually specify that the type is `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in the designer instead of any of the others it may think it is?

Comment: In the generated .cs file it shows as    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_action", DbType="NVarChar(MAX)", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]  
And in the XML it is <Column Name="action" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(MAX)" CanBeNull="true" UpdateCheck="Never" />.
the type in SQL Server is also nvarchar(MAX). I can't figure out why this isn't working because the other columns that are getting updated aren't causing problems

Comment: Does that column HAVE to be MAX? Could you get away with it being NVARCHAR(4000) or something like that? (or even 8000)

Comment: it doesn't have to be max, but even if it isn't it still causes the same problem.